# How to explain this weird lagging behaviour for touch input and keyboard input on iPad pro?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios10

`Device: iPad Pro (9.7 inch)
OS: iOS 10.2`

We have an app running in `single app mode`(using Apple configurator) on iPad.

When we load/run the app for first time everything runs okay.

But after about a week or two of continuous running, we see this lagging behaviour -  it starts taking a lot of time to register touch input or keyboard input.

Here's a video to illustrate this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlHc6uRVM_A&feature=youtu.be

You'll notice there's a significant latency in registering a touch or keyboard input.

Can someone help in pointing out what's happening here? It only happens after continuous usage of a week or two.

Is this somehow caused by our app?

Thanks,

Comment: Without any code and any Information about what you do? Hardly ...

Comment: @HAS Basically I am looking for any theoretical reason which could explain this lagging behaviour. What more info do you think would help?